# Button next to collapsible moves with text, should be on the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been learning bootstrap so I've been making a website to practice with it. I have a large red collapsible which displays some text when clicked on. I have a button next to it that moves below the text when clicked on, when I would like it to be on the bottom of the red button, and when the collapsible is clicked on, have the text come between the two buttons. I'm not sure how to move the button below and have the text come between.
EDIT: Bonus points if you can help me figure out why the "X" button on the modal is left of modal texts

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nwajax

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<script src="test.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <h1 id="main_head">This is a heading</h1>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2 div1">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical">
        <h4>These buttons don't work yet because I haven't implemented anything yet</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 div2">
      <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_collapse" class="btn-danger" id="coll_button">Collapsible</button>

      <div id="main_collapse" class="collapse">
        <h1>Some pretty neat random text that just appears when you click on the collapse thing</h1>
      </div>
      <!--Start modal-->
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!--End modal-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 div3">
      <div class="container">
        <h4>This is a dropdown menu</h4>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Click the dropdown menu
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu drop1">
            <li class="drop1"><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
            <li class="drop1"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
            <li class="drop1"><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="main_foot" class="container-fluid"><h1>This is a footer</h1>            
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a codepen (view should be changed to have display on the right/left, bootstrap is a bit weird with it) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joel,

The button next to the collapsible is disappearing from view when you click on the collapsible because the size of the text in between is h1. Change it to a smaller size for eg. h6

```
<h6>Some pretty neat random text that just appears when you click on the 
collapse thing</h6>
```

Also, the reason why you are seeing the close button on the model before the heading is because of way the markup is constructed. you have the markup for the button first followed by the heading change it to heading first followed by button like this:

```
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Comment: This helps, but how can I make the modal button below the collapsible and have the text of the collapsible come in between the two buttons. Thanks

Comment: simple solution would be to insert <br/> tag between the 'collapsible' and 'open modal' buttons. A better approach would be to use <div class="row">[content]</row> for each row you would like to insert. Have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp